# Python encoding in vim

Tags: python, vim, unicode, encoding

Trying to understand encoding/decoding/unicode business in Python2.7 with vim.

I have a unicode string **us** to which I assign some unicode string u'é'.

**Question 1**

How is **us** represented in memory? Is it a sequence of 32- bits long ints that unicode code points \u should consist of? Or is it kept in memory as a sequence of 8- bits long hex values \x in some default encoding?

**Question 2**

I see four different ways to set encoding for the unicode string **us**: #1 in the beginning of the test.py file; #2 as an argument of encode function; #3 as an argument for vim; #4 as a local encoding of the file system. So, what do all these four encodings (#1,#2,#3,#4) do?

```
$ vim test.py
_____________
#encoding: #1
us=u'é'
print us.encode(encoding='#2')
_____________
:set encoding=#3

$ locale | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.#4
LANGUAGE=
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x `unicode`s are encoded as either UCS-2 or UCS-4 depending on the options used when building it.

1. Source encoding as far as Python is concerned.
2. Encoding used to encode `us` as bytes when the code is executed.
3. Source encoding as far as vim is concerned. If this doesn't match #1 then expect trouble.
4. System encoding. Mostly affects [filesystem](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) and terminal output operations.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacio. So, #1 should be equal to #3. That's a good start. I assume further that #1==#3. When I assign u'é' to us -- can I be sure that us will be U+00E9 regardless of what specific encoding was chosen for #1?

Comment: Provided #1 and #3 support that character, yes.

Comment: Thanks again! Here is my confusion then: #1==#3==utf-8 and #2==latin1. Both should support u'é', but the output is �

Comment: Additionally, #2 should match #4 *if it is required*. Most of the time if #4 is set correctly then you don't need to encode when printing.

Comment: Indeed #4=='utf-8'!=#2=='latin1'. If I set #2='utf8' the output of the python code is correct é. Thanks! I'm though still confused why are there 4 parameters if there should be only 2 for proper functioning? P.S. And could you please elaborate on what it means "if it is required".

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1 - Storage

```
us = u'é'
```

This creates a Unicode character with a value of é - In Python 2.2+ Unicode characters are stored in UCS-2 or UCS-4 which use 2 or 4 byte long unsigned integers depending on a build time option.
Python 3.3+ uses UTF-8 which uses between 1 & 4 bytes for each character depending on the range it is in.

> The storage of Unicode strings now depends on the highest codepoint in
>   the string:
>
> - pure ASCII and Latin1 strings (U+0000-U+007F) use 1 byte per codepoint *0xxxxxxx*;
> - BMP strings *partial* (U+0080-U+07FF) use 2 bytes per codepoint *110xxxxx   10xxxxxx*;
> - BMP strings *remaining* (U+0800-U+FFFF) use 3 bytes per codepoint *1110xxxx 10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx*;
> - Other Plains (U+10000-U+10FFFF) use 4 bytes per codepoint *11110xxx 10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx*.

### Question 2 - Encoding

```
us=u'é'
```

Declares us to be a Unicode string stored as above, *note that in python 3 all strings are by default Unicode so the `u` can be omitted.*

```
print(us.encode('ascii', strict)) # encoding='#2')
```

Tells print how to attempt to translate the Unicode string for output, note that if you are using Python 3.3+ and a Unicode capable terminal/console you probably don't need to ever use this.

```
#set encoding=#3
```

Tells vim, emacs and a number of editors the encoding to use when displaying &/or editing the file *applies to all text files not just python*.

```
$ locale | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.#4
```

Is an operating system setting for the Locale Language that tells it how to display various things specifically which code page to use when displaying extended ASCII.

Comment: The storage of UTF-8 as you describe it cannot work. If you use up all bits in one byte for the 00..FF codepoints (and likewise 2 bytes for FFFF), how would you differentiate between the two in the encoding? There are not bits left for that! What you describe could be a valid fixed-width encoding (if there's a marker byte that describes the width), but it has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 encodes up to 7F (7bits) in 1 byte, 07ff (11 bits) in 2, FFFF (16 bits) in 3 and up to 10FFFF (21 bits) in 4 bytes. [source](https://research.swtch.com/utf8)

Comment: Python 2 uses UTF-16LE (narrow build) or UTF-32LE (wide build).  Python 3.3 does not use UTF-8 internally.  It uses (IIRC) latin1, UTF-16LE, or UTF-32LE as needed to represent the worst case code point in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't actually answer the question but I'm hoping it gives some more insight into this problem.

Answer to question 1: it shouldn't matter to the programmer how Unicode strings are represented internally in Python.

To question 2:

All the programmer should care about is that the data sink and source encoding requirements are known and correctly specified. I would assume that Python can correctly interpret UTF encoded files by reading the BOM and maybe even by making educated guesses but without the BOM it can be ambiguous how to handle bytes with the high bit set so it's advisable to either make sure the BOM is there or tell Python that the file is UTF-8 encoded if you're not sure.

There's a difference between "Unicode" and "UTF" that seems to be glossed-over above; "UTF" specifies the representation in storage (disk, memory, network packet) but "Unicode" is simply the fact that each character has a single value (code point) that ranges from 0 to 0x10FFFF. The various flavors of UTF *encode* that value into the appropriate storage. Working with encoded strings can be annoying though (as the character width is variable) so when strings are actually represented in memory often it's easier to expand them into some format that allows for easy manipulation. (This is touched on in a comment on another answer.)

If you want a Unicode string in Python pre-3, just type `u'<whatever>'` and in 3+ type `'<whatever>'`. You'll get Unicode and you can use `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` escapes if it's infeasible to just type the characters in directly. When you want to write the data, specify the encoding. UTF-8 is often the easiest to deal with and seems to be the most commonly used but you may have reason to use a UTF-16 flavor.

The takeaway here is that the encoding is just a way to transform Unicode data so that it can be persisted. The various flavors of UTF are just the encodings, they are not actually Unicode.